# Update CampaignMember Status picklist

Tags: campaign, campaign-member, status

I came across a weird problem when i was trying to replace the CampaignMember status picklist with 2 new values(Invited/Attended). I deleted Sent/Responded values.

It worked fine on the existing Campaign records. But when i created a New Campaign record and tried adding new CampaignMembers to the Campaign, i see only Sent/Responded and not the newly added ones. In the object field definition i see that the Sent/Responded are back.
How do i fix this or workaround this problem? I only want Invited/Attended.

Comment: Do you have record types on?

Comment: @DanWooding Yes, i do on the Campaign. Is it causing some issues?

Answer (score -1):

When you have a picklist field and record types on an object you can show/hide specific picklist values on the record type.

A downside of that customization ability is that when you add in new picklist values you need to add them to the record type as well. Else, they will be unavailable to be selected.

Go to Setup -> Customize -> Campaign Member -> Record Type -> Click the record type name -> Click Edit next to the picklist field -> Move value from available to selected.

Example:

[image: Available Record Type]

Comment: Was this helpful for you?